# Node.js Read from then recreate a JSON file

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, node.js

I am fairly new to NODE.JS, and want to take things to the next level.

I have a NODE.JS script that reads data from a feed and it is rendered as a HUGE JSON file. I then have webpages and mobile apps which use this file to render content using JQuery functions.

However I want to make this more efficient, and I want the node server to use the scripts I have written to extract content from the JSON file and break it down into smaller JSON files. This will stop the mobile apps and webpages from doing any rendering.

I already have the server running (express), and I want the server to listen for calls, and then extract the data from the JSON file and re-render it as a smaller file which is then delivered on request using res.json

I have the listener, the scripts, I am just missing the piece that will loop through data in a JSON file and output a another dynamic JSON file that can be rendered by res.json

Sample of the (first part of the) feed

```
{
  "RTPPDataMsgV1": {
    "owner": "Open Data",
    "timestamp": "1390097100000",
    "classification": "public",
    "Sender": {
      "application": "RTPP3",
      "organisation": "String"
    },
    "Publication": {
      "TopicID": "RTPP3/InternalPP"
    },
    "RTPPData": {
      "snapshotTStamp": "1390097100000",
      "SystemMsg": null,
      "RAGThresholds": [
        {
          "type": "TOC",
          "medium": "89",
          "good": "92"
        },
        {
          "type": "PPT",
          "medium": "85",
          "good": "91"
        }
      ],
      "PPT": {
        "rag": "W",
        "ragDisplayFlag": "Y",
        "text": "-1"
      },
```

This info is downloaded every 5 mins and always changes. I want the server to extract a tiny part of this and offer it up as another much smaller JSON file. Example if I just want the RagTHRESHOLDS section, or hell, even just the timestamp.

All this can take place in memory doent need to be written the OS as a file, I just need the server to take a request (in this case the RAG Thresholds), read the info, and offer it via  res.json('generated smaller JSON file') i.e

> ```
>     {
>       "type": "TOC",
>       "medium": "89",
>       "good": "92"
>     },
>     {
>       "type": "PPT",
>       "medium": "85",
>       "good": "91"
>     }
> ```

When extracting all the info on the current app, I have scripts that go through the masses of data several times, and its a problem on some of the older phones. If I was just able to offer up bit sized chunks and take the effort away from the phone it will speed things up drastically

Comment: Ok and what do you need from us?

Comment: Are you able to actually load this huge JSON file with the normal parser?  If so, just copy the parts you want to a regular object, and write that object.  Express will make it JSON for you.

Comment: depending on the json, it might not even be possible. if you have one large flat object or array, you can try several permutations of padding "}", "]", etc and try parsing it in a try/catch. syntax within string literals might confuse naive attempts however, so if your data is code or more json, it might be quite tricky.

Comment: added snippet of feed and more info about what I am looking for

Comment: I am guessing I need to read from the JSON, create an array or or string variable and then covert back to JSON using JSON.Stringify

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK getting there so I suspect I will be able to wrap this up now by converting the existing rendering code from my app.

IN the example about I used the following to extract the timestamp and render as

```
http://servername/ppm/timestamp.
```

I just have to create a string that holds all the JSON data and then just send it to the screen. I have run the output through a JSON checker and its all valid.

```
var express = require('express'),
    http = require('http');

var ppm = require('./data/ppm.json'); //this gets the entire JSON file

var timestamp = '{"timestamp" : "' + ppm.RTPPMDataMsgV1.timestamp + '"}';

var app = express()
    .use(express.bodyParser())
    .use(express.static('public'));

app.get('/ppm/timestamp', function (req, res) {
    res.send(timestamp);
});

app.get('/*', function (req, res) {
    res.json(404, {status: 'not found'});
});

http.createServer(app).listen(3000, function () {
    console.log("Server ready at http://localhost:3000");
});
```

This is only the simplest of examples. The more complex output will be filtered and masses of lists, but I have already constructed these loops and just need to tweak them. However now all this data extraction is done by the server, and will no longer need to be done by the phone / website which now just has to render the ouput